# Line Style using Graphics3D in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, 3d, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Consider the following :

```
cAxes = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0,0}, {1, 0, 0}}};

Graphics3D[{Line /@ cAxes}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

How can Style differently the 3 lines ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer above are good, but I want to show some alternatives.

I show that it is possible to use `Style` for this, and that `Tube` is an interesting alternative to `Line`.

```
cAxes = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
     0}, {1, 0, 0}}};

tubes = Tube@# ~Style~ #2 & ~MapThread~ {cAxes, {Red, Green, Blue}};

Graphics3D[tubes, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Could I send you something a little demo I am preparing ? I am struggling with some Graphics, but the code is to long !

Comment: @500 Yes, go ahead.  I should be able to spend some time on it today.

Comment: +1 for infix notation **~MapThread~**, that makes it "look" much more like the way that it works.

Comment: @Daniel, thank you.  I like to use infix notation a lot.  It has the significant advantage of letting me quickly know that the function is handling exactly two arguments, much as `@` or `//` indicate a single argument.  I would actually write the Style function above as `Tube@# ~Style~ #2 &` but I feared that others unfamiliar with infix would find it confusing.  Since this is not the first time I have received positive comments about infix however, I am going to stop worrying and use it liberally.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example:

```
colors = {Red, Green, Blue};
style = {Dashed, DotDashed, Dotted};
cAxes = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
     0}, {1, 0, 0}}};
Graphics3D[{#1, #2, Line@#3} & @@@ Transpose@{colors, style, cAxes}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Also remember that you can do the same with Plot3D if you need it:

```
colors = {Red, Green, Blue};
style = {Dashed, DotDashed, Dotted};
Plot3D[{}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive /@ Transpose@{colors, style}, 
 Boxed     -> False]
```

Comment: I am trying to decide if this is a good answer.  It is not clear to me if 500 wants to style axes, or simply chose those lines as an example.

Comment: @Mr. I don't know whether it is a good answer or not. I think of it just as a reminder of another possibility.

Comment: Okay, I like possibilities. +1 ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `MapThread`:

```
cAxes = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}};

Graphics3D[{
   MapThread[{#1, Line[#2]} &, {{Red, Blue, Green}, cAxes}]
   }, Boxed -> False]
```

Answer (score 3):

Untested (I don't have access to Mathematica right now):

```
Graphics3D[Transpose@{{Red, Green, Blue}, Line /@ cAxes}, Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: celtschk, congratulations on being the top new user this month as of today! http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks for notifying me about this. And also thanks for fixing the mistake in my code.