# Sphere Styling and Grid Spacing in Graphics3D

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, graphics3d

Please consider :

```
colors = {Red, Green, Blue};
style = {Thickness[.01], Thickness[.01], Thickness[.01]};
cAxes = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
 0}, {1, 0, 0}}};

Graphics3D[{{#1, #2, Line@#3} & @@@ Transpose@{colors, style, cAxes}, 
Blue, Specularity[White, 3], Sphere[{.5, .5, .5}, .1]}, 
Boxed -> False, FaceGrids -> All, 
FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed]]
```

Using Yoda`s solution on [How to Style Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115641/line-style-using-graphics3d-in-mathematica)

How could I **color the Sphere using GrayLevel** (I will manipulate it later).

And How could I have **denser FaceGrids** ? 10 Lines horizontally & Vertically. I also don`t understand why the Edges one are distant to one another.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always good practice to group the graphics object and its styles in a list, in case you need to quickly add another one with different styles. By that, I mean write it as `{Blue, Specularity[White, 3], Sphere[{.5, .5, .5}, .1]}`. Now you can easily add a `GrayLevel` term before `Sphere` and it'll work.

For the `FaceGrids`, I believe you'll have to manually define the lines at your desired spacing for each face. Here's an example for showing how to do it for one face.

```
Graphics3D[{{#1, #2, Line@#3} & @@@ 
   Transpose@{colors, style, cAxes}, {Blue, GrayLevel[0.3], Lighting -> "Neutral",
   Specularity[White, 3], Sphere[{.5, .5, .5}, .1]}}, Boxed -> False, 
 FaceGrids -> {{{0, 0, 1}, 
    Transpose@({#, #} & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1])}}, 
 FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed]]
```

[image]

The faces are defined as `±1` for the corresponding plane and the other two are zero. So `{0,0,1}` in my example corresponds to the `z=1` plane.

The list supplied to `FaceGrids` can be easily computed for each face, instead of manually entering them, <s>but I'll leave that to you :)</s>

#### EDIT:

Since you want a uniform mesh all around, define where you want the grid lines drawn as

```
gridList = Transpose@({#, #} & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1]);
```

Then, use the following for `FaceGrids`:

```
FaceGrids -> Join @@ Table[{RotateLeft[j {0, 0, 1}, i], gridList}, 
    {i, {0, 1, 2}}, {j, {-1, 1}}]
```

Here's how the result should look like with `PlotRangePadding -> None`:

[image]

Comment: This time you beat me to it :-)

Comment: Thank You, however I want this sphere to be in Black & White basically. Is it possible ?

Comment: Ah the lighting -> Neutral Does it !

Comment: @Yoda, What am I doing wrong :-) ? : FaceGrids -> {{#, Transpose@({#, #} & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1])}} & /@ {{0,
    0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}

Comment: @Yoda, FaceGrids -> 
 Function[ou, {ou, Transpose@({#, #} & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1])}] /@ {{0, 
    0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}} . This is the only thing I could do :-( It does not take any other value than 0 or -1 :-(

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Yoda's response:

- `Lighting -> "Neutral"` will allow grayscale object to show up as gray instead of with various colors.
- `PlotRangePadding -> None` will remove the spaces on the grid lines (depending on the setting for `PlotRange`.)

Answer (score 1):

Yoda beat me to typing out the `FaceGrids` setting (see [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FaceGrids.html)). But here is an alternative.

Instead of setting the `FaceGrids` setting explicitly, youcould also try setting `FrameTicks`, since by default the `FaceGrids` follow these, and then style the `FrameTicks` to be invisible using `Opacity`.